# Prove directly from the definition of the limit that $\lim (1/n!) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I'm having a hard time finding my number $N$.

This is what I have so far:

$$\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right| < \epsilon$$

$$ \frac{1}{n!} < \epsilon \Rightarrow n! > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

I know that $n!= n\cdot(n-1)\cdots2\cdot1$ , but I am not sure how to utilize this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $n! \ge n$ for all $n \ge 1$. Hence given $\epsilon > 0$, choosing $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ will result in $$\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right| = \frac{1}{n!} \le \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$$ for all $n > N$.

Answer (score 0):

One pretty standard real analysis proof is showing for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a natural number $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}< \varepsilon$. Make sure you prove this, or can use this result first. It follows immediately that $$\frac{1}{n!}<\frac{1}{N!} \leq \frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$$ for all $n>N$.